# Binary multiplication how to carry a 001 in case of adding 4 times 1?

Tags: binary

I am doing binary arithmetic for the first time and I want to know how to carry over 1+1+1+1 in binary multiplication 
$$\begin{align}
&1101000\\
&0101100\\
&1011000\\
&0001000\\
\end{align}$$

now the fourth column has 1+1+1+1=100, How can I carry it to the next column or any other such number 5=101 thanks.

Comment: sorry, thanks for notifying hawkeye :)

Comment: If the sum is, for exmplae, $100$, you notate $0$ and keep $10$ in mind.

Comment: Have you tried this in base ten? Adding so many numbers that the sum in one column exceeds $99$? I would think it would be more intuitive to see what to do in that case.

Comment: yeah interesting but it takes at least 12 step multiplication and I want to go to bathroom  nevermind @Arthur

Answer (score 1):

$1+1+1+1=100$, so it carries like this:

```
     10  
    1101000  
    0101100  
    1011000  
    0001000  
    -------  
       0100
```

Here I’ve shown only what you have after dealing with the four leftmost columns.

Comment: thanks @Brian so that is how carry over takes place. so in case of 101 I should write 1 and put 0 on the immediate left column and carry  1 to the column adjacent to the latter?

Comment: @Abomm: Yes, that’s correct.